# Azure AD B2B per application users

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b

I'm new to Azure and our organization is trying to build a multiple application that we and our partner organizations can access.

Per application, we inside our organization should be able to login. In addition, our partner for that particular app should also be able to login. Other partners for the other apps should not be able to login.

How can we achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the "enterprise application" for the app in question and set "User assignment required?" to Yes on the Properties tab.
Then you go to Users and groups tab and add the users and groups that you want to allow to access it (internals and partners).

By default without this setting all internal and partner users can sign in.

Comment: The quotes around the Enterprise applications is subtle. Good thing I tried to look for the app there even if I created it in Application Registrations. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah so the enterprise application is also known as the service principal, which is the application's identity in the directory. The app registration is a template for it essentially. Permissions that you consent to are always assigned to the service principal for example. This split makes more sense in the context of multi-tenant applications.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to a partner tenant which is not B2B then the above scenario will not help . The approach which can help you is to implement tenant restrictions .

> `Restrict-Access-To-Tenants: <permitted tenant list>` header is
> present, Azure AD only issues security tokens for the permitted
> tenants.

Reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/tenant-restrictions)